# How to install AceFEM in MacOS?

Tags: finite-element-method, packages, acegen

I downloaded the Evaluation/student version and ran Install.nb according to the official installation instructions^[1](http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/User/AceInstallation.htm), it returned some errors as follows.

> Cannot load installation package. Problematic file:
> /Users/AceGen/AceCommon/InstallAll.m Check: 1) that the file in fact
> exists 2) that you have administrator permissions 3) Close
> Mathematica, delete any old installation files and repeat installation
> procedure

I feel it's because of 2 or 3, but I don't know how to run this installation process with administrator privileges, and  I don't know how to delete the old installation files. I'm not very familiar with macOS.

Very grateful for your comments and help!